# $i\epsilon$ versus $2i \epsilon E_k$ in the propagator

Tags: quantum-field-theory, fourier-transform, propagator

The Fourier Transform of the propagator can be written as
$$\tilde{\Delta}(k) = \frac{i}{k^2-m^2+i\epsilon}  \tag{1}                  $$
which is then "factored" into
$$ = \frac{i}{\left(  k^0-E_k +i\epsilon   \right)\left( k^0+E_k-i\epsilon   \right)}  \tag{2}   $$
But, when you expand out $(2)$ you get
$$  = \frac{i}{\left( k^0         \right)^2 -m^2 + \color{red}{2E_k}i \epsilon              }.   \tag{3}       $$
The usual argument is that $2E_k$ is a positive number, so it can just be absorbed into $\epsilon$ and when $\epsilon$ is taken to $0$ then it overwhelms whatever $2E_k$ is and so $(1)$ is the appropriate expression for the propagator.

This question is addressed in this [previous question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/110352/why-can-we-simply-absorb-the-positive-coefficient-of-i-epsilon-in-a-propagator), though I don't think particularly adequately.

My question is, my field theory professor mentioned that he has heard that using $(1)$ in favor of $(3)$ comes back to bite you sometimes, and referenced Steven Weinberg, but didn't elaborate.  When $\textit{would}$ using $(1)$ not be sufficient?